# How to format point's line color of a line chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to change line color of one point on my chart. The chart series is line series. I want to change a line color of the second point on this series.

What I want to do is basically this:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
'pts < this is points object
'pt < this is point object

pt = pts.Item(3)
pt.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150)
```

All objects are referenced correctly, everything works. It does not produce any error but this code formats line of a marker (even though the line series has no markers!). No matter what I try, I format the marker line (aka border). I cannot find a way to format a specific point's line (like in the image above).

Is there any "hidden" combination to allow me to do this?

Comment: I am afraid it is not as you say... A point is an object. `pt = pts.Item(3)` must raise an error. It should be set as: `Set pt = pts.Item(3)`. Of course, `pts` should also be correctly set... You maybe have somewhere in your code `On Error Resume  Next` and that's why it looks like "everything works". Please, edit your question and show us all involved code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the foreColor of the point's Format.Line, like so:

```
Sub colorSegment()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As Chart
 
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
 
    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        
        .Points(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150)
        .Points(7).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150)
    
       End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]